# How to override urlRequest in WKWebView

Tags: ios, swift, wkwebview

I am a newbie here for ios, swift and Xcode.

I have a component of `WKWebView`. And I want to add some headers while `onClick` for redirecting to another page in the `WKWebView`. How can I override or add the headers? If in `Android` version, I can do like:

```
webView.setWebViewClient(new WebViewClient() {

       :
        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, WebResourceRequest url) {
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT >= Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                view.loadUrl(url.getUrl().toString(), extraHeader);
            }
            return true;
        }

        :

        @Override
        public boolean shouldOverrideUrlLoading(WebView view, String url) {
            if (android.os.Build.VERSION.SDK_INT < Build.VERSION_CODES.N) {
                view.loadUrl(url, extraHeader);
            }
            return true;

        }

        :
}
```

I have already done like this:

```
override func viewDidLoad() {

        super.viewDidLoad()

        // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.


        let url = URL(string: BASE_URL)

        let request = NSMutableURLRequest(url: url!)

        request.addValue(MOBILE, forHTTPHeaderField: X_CLIENT_TYPE)



        self.webView.load(request as URLRequest)

 }
```

But, the code above is only for first loading. If I click a link in `WKWebView`, the headers are gone.

So, it is my pleasure for anyone can help me...

env:

> - XCode v. 9.3

Answer (score 3):

I have already found a solution:

```
func webView(_ webView: WKWebView, decidePolicyFor navigationAction: WKNavigationAction, decisionHandler: @escaping (WKNavigationActionPolicy) -> Void) {

        print("decidePolicyFor")

        let request = navigationAction.request

        print("request: ", request)



        if ( (request.url?.absoluteString.hasPrefix(BASE_URL))! && request is NSMutableURLRequest) {

            print("NSMutableURLRequest")

            let mutableRequest = request as! NSMutableURLRequest;

            let clientType = mutableRequest.value(forHTTPHeaderField: X_CLIENT_TYPE) as String?

            print("clientType: ", clientType)



            if (clientType != nil && clientType == MOBILE) {

                print("client type is MOBILE")

            } else {

                print("add client type MOBILE")

                mutableRequest.addValue(MOBILE, forHTTPHeaderField: X_CLIENT_TYPE)

                webView.load(mutableRequest as URLRequest)

            }

            decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicy.allow)

        } else {

            print("NOT NSMutableURLRequest")



            decisionHandler(WKNavigationActionPolicy.allow)

        }

    }
```

Answer (score 1):

```
var request = URLRequest(url: URL(string: url)!)
request.httpMethod = "POST"
// If you have post parameter pass here 
let postString = "key=\(Value!)&Key=\(Value!)"
request.httpBody = postString.data(using: .utf8)

// Set your Header here   
request.setValue("MOBILE", forHTTPHeaderField:"X_CLIENT_TYPE")

 if request != nil
    {
        webView.loadRequest(request)
        webView.delegate = self     
    }
```

You Can Do for Second Click

```
func webView(_ webView: UIWebView, shouldStartLoadWith request: URLRequest, navigationType:
    UIWebViewNavigationType) -> Bool
{
    var Myrequest  = URLRequest.init(url: request.url!)

    Myrequest.setValue("MOBILE", forHTTPHeaderField:"X_CLIENT_TYPE")

    webView.loadRequest(Myrequest)

    true
}
```

Comment: It is not working.. I click some links in the page on `WKWebView`, the headers are gone.. It is working for first loading..

Comment: Sorry, for `the func` is not working too, and I already added `UIWebViewDelegate`. Hmmmm, I used `WKWebView` not `UIWebView`..

Comment: Its useful or not ?

Comment: What happen ? you have to manage with boolean variable because here we are adding header in request and load webview again so if you load this method will trigger and this will go in loop so you have to load 1 url only ones